# I am trying to position an img element however when I use the coordinate properties it is not going where I presume it should go

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="top-container">
          <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
          <h1>Placeholder</h1>
          <p>Placeholder</p>
          <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
          <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .top-container {
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 70px;
      background-color: #defcf9;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .top-cloud {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100px;
    }
    
    .bottom-cloud {
      position: absolute;
      left: 400px;
    }
```

Before adding the coordinate properties the webpage looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xsjF.png

After adding the coordinate properties the webpage looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmdfb.png

Comment: Which property are you referring as `coordinate properties`?

Comment: Manas, I think they are referring to the `position: absolute` declarations. And the coordinates as the top/right/bottom/left pixel positions.

Comment: yes I am refering to top,right, bottom and left, sorry for the lack of clarification

Answer (score 0):

Since the provided reference image is only static, there may be some elements that need some editing, but a method to start with would be like the following.

Here, the mountain is set to be at the bottom of the `top-container` element, and this would stay that way even if more placeholder text is added. This image is also set to center, while the clouds are set to static positions. To make sure text would still be atop all the image, a `z-index` was added to all elements to set stack height.

Since there were no supplied images, there is placeholder CSS code set for the moment to give a rough idea.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 400px;
  background-color: #defcf9;
  position: relative;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 50;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 50;
}

img.mountain {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: brown;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

.text_content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <div class="text_content">
    <h1>Placeholder</h1>
    <p>Placeholder</p>
  </div>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for you detailed response. When using your code answer I found that using the left and top properties worked just fine however when using bottom the cloud image element would go to the bottom of the div and using right would make the cloud img element go to the far right of the screen. (Maybe this is supposed to happen? My understanding of coordinate properties is that it creates a space similar to the margin property) Do you know why this is? (I apologize if I sound very annoying in this comment)

Comment: I know it's a bit hard to describe in words—right now, the clouds are set to static horizontal positions. You could try changing the position properties to fluid values such as: `left: 30%;`, for instance. The mountain was set to align to the bottom of the parent element, but you could set the height for that as a fixed dimension. Hope this helps.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for your response and time. Unfortunately at my current level I do not have a solid understanding of this topics, I will continue learning CSS and come back to this question. Once again thank you for your responses